# Making a list of all combinations of 2 letters and 4 numbers

Tags: java, eclipse

I have been trying to create a code that can make a list of all combinations of 2 letters and 4 numbers

> EX: aa1111, ab1111

the only thing that i can come up with are programs that print combinations that are against my outline

> EX: aatc9e, gj3ru7

What can I do that makes it so it stops at two letters and goes to the four numbers?

Comment: you forgot to paste your code

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it as 3 while loops, and add each one.

It's also useful that Characters can be both letters and numbers.

Given you haven't added any code, here's some dirty pseudo code:

```
Output = New Array[]
char characterOne = 'A'
while characterOne < 26:
     char characterTwo = 'A'
     while characterTwo <26:
         char Number = '0000'
         while Number < 9999:
             Output.add (CharacterOne + CharacterTwo + Number.toString)
             Number ++
         characterTwo++
     characterOne++
```

Remember; stack overflow likes specificity, include your code next time.

Answer (score 0):

This process is rather involved as you are going to generate combinations of strings from

`aa0000 - zz9999`.

It can be done with one `while` loop, an `Array` of two `String`s, and one `int`.  You'll have to know when your `number > 9999` so you can increment the second letter (`letters[1]`), then you have to know when the second letter is about to pass "z" so you can increment the first letter (`letters[0]`) and start the second letter back at "a".

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    String[] letters = new String[] { "a", "a" };
    int number = 0;

    String combination = letters[0] + letters[1] + String.format("%04d", number);
    while (!combination.contentEquals("zz9999")) {
        // Output the combination
        System.out.println(combination);

        number++;
        if (number > 9999) {
            int letterIndex = alphabet.indexOf(letters[1]) + 1;
            if (letterIndex < alphabet.length()) {
                // Get the next letter in the alphabet
                letters[1] = String.valueOf(alphabet.charAt(letterIndex));
            } else {
                // We've passed z, so we need to increment the first letter
                letterIndex = alphabet.indexOf(letters[0]) + 1;
                if (letterIndex < alphabet.length()) {
                    // Get the next letter in the alphabet
                    letters[0] = String.valueOf(alphabet.charAt(letterIndex));
                }

                // Start back at letter a
                letters[1] = "a";
            }

            // Start back at zero 
            number = 0;
        }

        // Format the next combination
        combination = letters[0] + letters[1] + String.format("%04d", number);
    }
    // Print the last combination
    System.out.println(combination);
}
```

Seeing that this is your first question on SO, next time post code that shows an actual attempt to your question.  Don't just post a question without giving an effort to solve it yourself, and expect SO to solve it for you.